# Ocultar boton en webview android studio

Tags: javascript, android, html5, webview

estoy tratando de ocultar un botón html en un webview, he conseguido ocultar elementos, pero este boton se carga en un popup cuando pinchas para hacer un login, por lo que el boton cuando carga la página aún no existe.
He intentado llamar una función de javascript dentro del webview pero no lo acaba de ocultar. He dado mil vueltas al asunto y ya no se por donde tirar. 
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Dejo el codigo tanto del html como del MainActiviti.java

Codigo en la página html

```
<li class="pf-login-register" id="pf-login-trigger-button-mobi" onClick="ShowHiddenGoogle()">

<script> 
function ShowHiddenGoogle() { 
    Android.HiddenGoogle();
}
</script>
```

Codigo en el MainActivity.java

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }    


        /** Show a toast from the web page */
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void HiddenGoogle() {
//Mensaje de prueba para ver si funciona la función
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "prueba", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " + "document.getElementById('pf-ajax-logingoogle').style.display='none';})()");
            }
    }
```

Comment: quizás podrías detectar cuando va a cargar el popup con onLoadResource.

Comment: Gracias por contestar... java no lo controlo... podrias especificar, he buscado la funcion pero no me ha quedado muy claro.